# ML Search Grammar

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I was wondering what I want is possible using search grammar.. For eg:let us assume 3 documents

```
 doc 1:
    <seq>
       <chain><name>PL-1</name></chain>
    </seq>
doc 2:
    <seq>
         <chain><name>PL-1</name></chain>
         <chain><name>PL-2</name></chain>
     </seq>
doc 3:
    <seq>
         <chain><name>PL-1</name></chain>
         <chain><name>PL-2</name></chain>
         <chain><name>PL-3</name></chain>
     </seq>
```

I want to search for documents containing chain names "PL-1". and nothing else.. so for this search criteria I need to get only doc 1, if I want to search for PL-1 and PL-2, I should get only doc2

Is this possible with Search Grammar ??

Answer (score 1):

The default search grammar uses minus (`-`) as a starter token that translates into a negated query, so you could use that:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:parse("PL-1 -PL-2 -PL-3")
```

That will return the query for your first example, matching doc 1:

```
<cts:and-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
  <cts:word-query>
    <cts:text xml:lang="en">PL-1</cts:text>
  </cts:word-query>
  <cts:not-query>
    <cts:word-query>
      <cts:text xml:lang="en">PL-2</cts:text>
    </cts:word-query>
  </cts:not-query>
  <cts:not-query>
    <cts:word-query>
      <cts:text xml:lang="en">PL-3</cts:text>
    </cts:word-query>
  </cts:not-query>
</cts:and-query>
```

Using the same method, you could create a string for the query that matches only doc 2:

```
PL-1 PL-2 -PL-3
```

Comment: Actually I do not how many chains are there in a document.. So this will not work as I am looking for documents containing only names specified in the search string

Comment: @Ravi That's actually a very different question from the one you asked. You need to state all your constraints; otherwise, why would anyone answer with a solution to a harder problem than the one you asked? What you want is possible, but more complicated, so please create a new question.